# Difficulty answering self study homework using a dictionary

Tags: c#

Hello there again dear friends. I do not for the word of me understand what is going on in this code. I'm trying to implement a dictionary that counts the instances that a word pops up disregarding upper case or not. It keeps showing **"isthis"** and I dont know where its coming from. How do i rectify this?

The question is as such

> Write a program that counts how many times each word from a given
>   text file words.txt appears in it. The result words should be ordered by
>   their number of occurrences in the text.

Here is the code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Chapter_18_Question_3
{
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const string path = "words.txt";
        string line;
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(path))
        {
             line = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        string text = line.ToLower();
        string tmp = Regex.Replace(text, "[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]", "");
        string[] newText = tmp.Split(' '); 

        var table = new SortedDictionary<string, int>();
        foreach(var item in newText)
        {
            if(!table.ContainsKey(item))
            {
                table.Add(item, 1);
            }

            else
            {
                table[item] += 1;
            }
        }
        foreach (var item in table)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The word {0} appeared {1} times",
                item.Key, item.Value);
        }

    }
}
```

My text is this:

"This is the TEXT. Text, text, text – THIS TEXT! Is this the text?"

And the output is this

> The word  appeared 1 times
>
> The word is appeared 1 times
>
> The word isthis appeared 1 times
>
> The word text appeared 6 times
>
> The word the appeared 2 times
>
> The word this appeared 2 times

Comment: Running the code you provided - it works as expected, there's no `thisis`. If I had to guess, your text file might contain a space-looking character that's not an actual space and then you're removing it here: `string tmp = Regex.Replace(text, "[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]", "");`

Comment: I don't think that's really your text. Here's a test: https://dotnetfiddle.net/NzdPcL. Look more closely at the contents of your file.

Answer (score 0):

If I were to guess, I'd say that your file contains a line break (LF or CRLF) that gets replaced by your regex (which only allows letters and spaces).

For instance, if the file contents were:

```
This
is the text.
```

The line break between *This* and *is* would be removed, leaving you with the text:

```
Thisis the text.
```

If this is the case, you might want to use `"[^a-zA-Z0-9 \r\n]"` instead as a replacement pattern.